# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myapp'

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis, connection-string

I had a small database app that direct connected to its database via this conn string - 
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CalendarPhotos.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

This all worked fine until today I attached that database to SQL Server Management Studio so that I could quickly and easily edit some data. Up till then this database had never been attached.

Having done the edits and detached teh database, I now find that I get teh following error when browsing localhost
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Calendar Comp'.

The IIS app pool setting is currently ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I do not know if it was set to that prior to the attach.

Can anyone advise how to get this thing running again please?

Comment: Hi @Malcom perhaps you need to give Asp.Net  permissions to your sql database. this can be done in SQL Server Management Studio under security. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Fernan,  I'm not at work so cannot check this but all the permissions were ok before I attached the db to SSMS. The whole app has been running nicely for some 6 months up until I did the attach/detach.  replacing the dB with a backup gets things going again so SSMS has altered the dB somehow but I don't know how.

Comment: I found this is sql documentation: "File access permissions are set during a number of database operations, including detaching or attaching a database"